# Who can give PAT test labels out in the UK?

Tags: electrical

Can any registered electrician give an item a PAT test label, or does it require membership of an additional trade body of some kind?

Also, is it legal to sell these items to certified electricians when working in a shop? If so, do they require any particular identification to buy them?

Comment: This appears to be a legal question which is off topic for this site.

Comment: I would be happy to have it moved to legal if you think it more appropriate.

Comment: I'll ping Legal.SE if others here feel it's off topic for DIY site. Since I'm not familiar with UK electrical, I posted in the chat room here for more opinions first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal advice and for a business environment.

Comment: You could move this to The Workplace if you like. Actually, since it's been closed already I'll raise it there.

Comment: Oh, I'm not allowed anymore. Move to the Lawyer one then, maybe?

Comment: Others in the chat agreed this was off topic. Since it looks like that also got you a useful answer, are you still interested in having it migrated to law.se? I suspect this is too far into a specific practical case for them, but happy to ask if you'd like.

Comment: It's ok to leave it here. Anything I post on The Workplace just gets downvoted anyway. Literally anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PAT test labels have no legal protection in the UK.

There is no legal reason to stop any person purchasing PAT test labels.

Portable Appliance Testing is not mandated in UK law.

In many situations (e.g. a typical office) simple visual inspection every two or three years may be adequate. This can be done by any unqualified person. If desired by management, they can stick a PAT label on anything they have looked at.

> There is a widely held misconception that all portable equipment needs portable appliance testing and often annually. The law has not changed. There is no requirement to carry out portable appliance tests (PAT) ... You don't need to be a qualified electrician to carry out inspection or testing, but some basic knowledge is needed.

- HSE Case 9.

---

References

- [Health and Safety Executive (HSE) - *"Maintaining portable electrical equipment in offices and other low-risk environments"*](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiF7traj_DMAhWJCcAKHYpFDtwQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hse.gov.uk%2Fpubns%2Findg236.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFDT6qCQQFQs37BxbxAxM7s2Y8roA&sig2=xrqSjLU4RPoeSECk-qg7vw)
- [HSE Case 9](http://www.hse.gov.uk/myth/myth-busting/2012/case009-pattesting.htm)

Comment: Ooohhhh, looks like the British Heart Foundation Customer Service Advisor test is dispensing incorrect info! Someone's head will be for the chop when it's found out... ;)